# Best way to compress an incrementing data

Tags: c, compression, x86-64

I have a vector where I keep an incrementing data. Normally each element of the vector is a 64 bit long variable. However, it is quite possible that difference between two successive elements is quite small, so for example we can have a sequence as follows.

```
1, 34, 37, 42, 45, 1098, 1200, 1211, 1938
```

What is the best way of compressing this data. Would it be ideal to just keep the differences, and have a header byte which defines how big is the difference, whether it is only a byte, word, double word etc, or are there even better ways of compressing such incremental data?

### EDIT

I need to compress online, that is while putting data in the vector. You may assume a dynamically expanding vector.

Comment: do you have a fixed length vector that you want to compress and store entirely, or do you have a process that generates values that need to be compressed and stored on-line?

Comment: Do you mean when saving this data to disk, or do you expect to be able to compress while in memory? If the latter, what operations do you expect to be able to do on the data?

Comment: I mean on the fly. See below EDIT in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a very simple strategy for when the increments are typically small:

1. If the increment is <2**7, emit it as a single byte with the highest bit set to zero:

   ```
   0xxxxxxx
   ```
2. Else, if the increment is <2**14, emit it as two bytes with highest bits one and zero, respectively:

   ```
   1xxxxxxx 0xxxxxxx
   ```
3. Extend this to larger increments in the obvious way. An eighth bit set to one means "wait, there's more coming". Zero means "end of integer".

I remember seeing this coding scheme being suggested for bigints in some RFC or maybe an `internet-draft`, but I seem unable to retrieve it right now. Alternatively, you can reuse the UTF-8 encoding scheme for some improved error detection at the expense of less efficient encoding (and you may have to extend it if you want to go beyond 64-bit integers).

Comment: This is the same as ["variable-length quantity (VLQ)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/variable-length_quantity), right? There exist other techniques that give better compression, but they are all much more complicated.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I meant. Thanks, I knew this encoding had a name, but I keep forgetting it!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need something (as you already said yourself) like a differential modulation. Maybe this gives you some inspiration: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_pulse-code_modulation